# Using LibCurl to synchronise IMAP email

Tags: c++, imap, libcurl

I'm trying to use LibCurl to synchronise my IMAP email so that, in effect, I have an email client which will retrieve new email into a folder periodically as it arrives.  It shouldn't do anything clever like filtering - just get the email.

I have some ideas on how this might be achieved - but the trouble is that the only options I can see for LibCurl are options like NEW and RECENT which (presumably) won't work if another email client comes along and retrieves / reads / responds to the email in the meantime.  I could just retrieve emails which arrived since the last collection time - except that LibCurl doesn't allow granularity for retrieval any more precise than Day.

The code that I've written so far is as follows (based on the examples in the LibCurl documentation):

```
#include "curl_imap.h"

using namespace std;

std::string homedirectory;

int curl_changedir(string path, CURL* curl) {
    string newpath;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, path.c_str());         
    return 0;
}

CURL* curl_login(char* username, char* password) {
    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;

    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, username);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, password);
        curl_changedir(homedirectory, curl);
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
    return curl;
}

int fetch_imap_inbox(IMAPSetting &imap) {
    homedirectory.assign(imap.url,strlen(imap.url));    
    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl = curl_login(imap.username, imap.password);
    if (curl) {
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if(res != CURLE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    return (int)res;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how I might achieve what I want to achieve?  I've been experimenting with Gmail so far (which also raises the question of how to use LibCurl without having to reduce Gmail's security settings!)

Comment: Are you aware of fetchmail?  That's what it does.

Comment: I am - but it doesn't really fit my usecase. What I want is a single app which gets my email and then processes it further. I realise that i could achieve the same effect with fetchmail and then a bunch of scripts - but, like a rats nest of wires, that feels messy to me. I'd rather (if possible) use LibCurl and have a nice integrated solution.